# Does Hyperdimension Neptunia MK II import data from the the first game?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2, hyperdimension-neptunia

i've brought the first game from an online UK store but they are out of stock of the second, i've been watching it for almost 2 months now and it still hasn't been restocked.

i could see if i can buy it locally (Australia Region 4) but i'm worried that if i can import data from the previous game i wont be able to import it into Mk II if it's from a different region (.hack//G.U allowed .hack saves to be imported but only if the save game was from an NTSC copy of .hack, any PAL save of .hack isn't picked up in .hack//G.U)

so, to try and set my mind at ease, Does Hyperdimension Neptunia MK II import data from the the first game and if so, would it matter if the 2 games came from different regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started playing it and it seems it doesn't import data, also, it seems the game is avaliable for download on the Playstation Store, not sure of the pricing for the UK but the US has it for $50 and Aus for $90 (once again, we're getting charged for almost twice the amount for a DIGITAL DOWNLOAD),  so if you want to get MK II in the same region as the original you should be able to buy it from the Playstation Store